# Gmap vue save polyline, polygon and load geojson onto google map

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-maps, nuxt.js, geojson

I am have a vuejs/nuxtjs application using the [gmap-vue package](https://github.com/diegoazh/gmap-vue) which is a fork of vue-google-maps. I have followed the [drawing manager with slot example](https://diegoazh.github.io/gmap-vue/examples/drawing-manager-with-slot.html#live-example) which is working as shown on the document, good times!

But...

I would like to do two more things

1. Save the data that I added to the map, how do I access it?
2. How to load geojson onto the map and then edit it.

Examle below:

[image]

More information from further investigation.
I am trying to build up data in the form of geojson

```
let shapes = [];

for(let shape in this.shapes){
    let tmp = {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "id": this.shapes[shape].id || null,
            "zIndex": this.shapes[shape].zIndex || null
         },
          "geometry": {
            "type": this.shapes[shape].type,
            "coordinates": // where to find shape coordinates?
          }
        };

       shapes.push(tmp)

      }
      console.log(JSON.stringify(shapes));
```

displays the following in the console.log

```
[
  {
    "type":"Feature",
    "properties":{
      "id":null,
      "zIndex":null
    },
    "geometry":{
       "type":"polygon",
       "coordinates": // where to find coordinates?
     }
  }
]
```

```
console.log[this.shapes[shape]];
```

returns

```
{__ob__: Observer}
overlay: (...)
type: (...)
```

How can I access the coordinates?

Comment: Not sure exactly how but for the `1.`, you could probably try to use `this.$refs.mapRef` and inspect the various changes/objects attached to it.

Comment: hi @kissu I found this in the docs and it is working ```this.$refs.mapRef.$mapPromise.then((map) => {
      })``` map gives me access to some methods

Comment: I am looking but I think ```map.loadGeoJson();``` wants a .json file to load.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else looking for an answer, I hope this helps you out.

```
const newShapes = [];
  this.shapes.forEach((shape) => {
    const coords = [];
    shape.overlay.latLngs.getArray().forEach((latLng) => {
      coords.push([latLng.lat, latLng.lng]);
    });
    newShapes.push({
      type: 'Feature',
      geometry: {
        type: shape.type,
        coordinates: coords,
      },
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

As shown here: https://diegoazh.github.io/gmap-vue/#getting-a-map-reference

```js
this.$refs.mapRef.$mapPromise.then((map) => {
  map.panTo({lat: 1.38, lng: 103.80})
})
```

is working pretty great.

---

```html
<gmap-drawing-manager ref="drawingRef">
```

and

```html
<gmap-drawing-manager :shapes="shapes" ref="drawingRef">
```

allows to access the same information with `this.shapes`!

Comment: tryng this now ```<gmap-drawing-manager ref="drawingRef">``` ref then allows me to access ```this.$refs.drawingRef.shapes```

Comment: alternatively ```<gmap-drawing-manager :shapes="shapes" ref="drawingRef">``` allows me to access the same information with ```this.shapes```

Comment: I think I am probably being a bit unclear. I am trying to save shapes and I am not sure how to access the data and then load the shapes onto the map when again when I refresh the page.

Comment: It looks like kissu you are updating the answer to include what I am adding in the comments. I hope my comment above makes it clearer, not sure why the question got a -1.

Comment: Your question actually do have a `+1 / -2` and `2 close votes` because it `needs more focus`. Nothing negative from my side but some other people may have not liked it for some reason.

Comment: Ok, I have edited the question to include more information from further investigation on my side. Hopefully no more -votes ;P